# yii CDbCriteria select not working?

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, cactivedataprovider

I need to edit the query of my CGridView

so in my model I'm changing the function search() as follow:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = "links.title, links.url, groups.title as grouptitle";
$criteria->join = " join groups on links.id_group = groups.id_group";
$criteria->addCondition("links.id_user = '" . Yii::app()->user->getId() . "'");

return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
));
```

But from my view I get an error which shows me that the select is incorrect:

```
The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `links` `t` join groups on links.id_group = groups.id_group WHERE links.id_user = '1'
```

why so?

Comment: FROM the query you need change the link to t
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `links` `t` join groups on t.id_group = groups.id_group WHERE t.id_user = '1

Comment: @chen ? what do you mean?

Comment: because the default table alias was `t` in Yii no `links`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default [table alias](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#alias-detail) is `t` unless set explicitly. You can do this by:

```
$criteria->alias = 'links';
```